# Python MailMerge refest word doc

Tags: python, cpu-word, mailmerge

I'm looking for a way to refresh my Word document. On Word, the basic command is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> for all refresh in page but there is a way to do it from python.

In fact, I bring an image on my Word document, but each time I have to refresh the doc to make the image appear, can we automate this?

Comment: What do you mean by refresh the document? What is there to refresh? It reflects each change you make the moment you make it.

Comment: I think the good word is update sry. I need to update my image to show in my Word doc.